# superscript not showing up in joomla article

Tags: html, css, joomla

I cannot get the superscript `<sup></sup>` to show up in any Joomla article. I tried changing the editor and also not using the editor, but that did not help.

Comment: What editor are you using? TinyMCE? Are other html tags working like <sub> or <hr>

Answer (score 0):

Since enclosing in 
    <sup>Superscript</sup>
tags should work, you need to make certain that the 'input format' in Joomla is set to accept HTML tags, as many CMS editors use filters or other markup languages such as textile.  Do other html tags work for you in joomla?  Like:

```
<b></b>
```

Comment: It unfortunately can depend a lot on how your Joomla set up is configured, but one way to do it (manually and painfully) is following these directions:  [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4506611_use-html-joomla.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see use the superscript because tinyMCE clean up HTML tags.

Go to plugins and edit [**Editor - TinyMCE 2.0**]

Set Code Cleanup on Startup to Off
and set Code cleanup on save to never.

Then it will work perfectly